# Providing Up (aka Back) Navigation - with UI Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, up-navigation, up-button

The Google doc [Providing Up Navigation](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html) explains, how to display an *Up button* in an application with **several** Activities (by specifying "parent" Activities in AndroidManifest.xml):

[image: screenshot]

However I am working on a Bluetooth application (starting with `minSdkVersion=18`) which has a **single** MainActivity and 3 Fragments:

- MainFragment.java
- SettingsFragment.java
- ScanningFragment.java

So I have changed the base class to `ActionBarActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity 
                          implements BleWrapperUiCallbacks {
```

And I call the `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)` method:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);  
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_root);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

This displays the *Up button* in my app, however I still have 3 questions:

1. How to hide the *Up button* (when I am showing the MainFragment)?
2. How to "wire" the *Up button* - currently touching it does nothing?
3. What to use instead of the following line in my AndroidManifest.xml?

> android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar"

Comment: check this tutorial  http://tech-papers.org/android-working-with-action-bar/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can answer the second question for providing the up navigation by override this method :

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
switch (item.getItemId()) {
// Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
case android.R.id.home:
    NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
    return true;
}
return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```